# How to pass jarsigner.exe passphrase via commandline?

Tags: jarsigner

I know that this is unsafe, but is there any easy way to pass passphrase to the jarsigner.exe:

> jrsigner.exe -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore ...
>
> Enter Passphrase for keystore:

I am running it in batch file.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Well, why do you not simply use the corresponding parameters?

```
jarsigner -keystore my-keystore -storetype jceks -storepass "test" -keypass "test" my-archive.jar xander
```

Broken down into separate lines for better readability (but you have to put all parameters on one line, of course):

```
jarsigner
  -keystore my-keystore    # keystore path name
  -storetype jceks         # keystore type (whatever format yours is in)
  -storepass "test"        # keystore password
  -keypass "test"          # private key password
  my-archive.jar           # JAR path name
  xander                   # key name (alias)
```

**Update:** Please note with regard to passwords that

- enclosing passwords in double or single quotes is optional if the passwords contain no special characters.
- on the Windows command line you have to use double quotes enclosing passwords with special characters such as space. I am mentioning that because someone previously edited my answer and used single quotes which would simply fail on the Windows command line.
- on UNIX-like systems like Linux or also in the Windows Git Bash or Cygwin you can use both double or single quotes, but with double quotes beware of shell expansion.

Comment: even if -keypass _my_coolpass_ is in command line, it still asks for it

Comment: You wrote the error message reads: "Enter Passphrase for **keystore**" So you are not missing the password for the private key but the one for the keystore itself. Next time just read my answer more carefully, please. I documented both passwords. The command line help for the tool also describes it.

Comment: Tons of thanx, dear @kriegaex

Comment: You have given me the gift of Time.  Thank you Sir!

Comment: This is exactly why people like me love SO. I wish I could upvote this multiple times :)

Comment: Tons of thanks sir, `-storepass` just work to .keystore password... :)